# jPlayer time issue

Tags: jquery, jplayer

I'm using jPlayer on my website and I want to change next thing, on the songs when you press the play button (after you listened that song already) the song start from the beginning.

```
 $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
    ready: function () {
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            title: "Stirring of a fool",
            mp3: "albume/album1/melodii/1.mp3"
        });
    },
    play: function() { // To avoid multiple jPlayers playing together.
        $(this).jPlayer("pauseOthers");
    },
    swfPath: "../../js",
    supplied: "mp3",
    wmode: "window",
    globalVolume: true,
    useStateClassSkin: true,
    autoBlur: false,
    smoothPlayBar: true,
    keyEnabled: true
});
```

At the moment, the song starts from where I left.

Comment: autoPlay: true, add this and try.

Comment: It's the same thing.. Anyway I won't songs play automatically just start every  time when I press play from 0:00

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding `pause` event handler and reset position to `0` if the song is paused. If the song has been played to the end or hasn't been started, it should start from the beginning anyway.

Your code should be modified as follows:

```
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
    ready: function () {
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            title: "Stirring of a fool",
            mp3: "albume/album1/melodii/1.mp3"
        });
    },
    play: function() { // To avoid multiple jPlayers playing together.
        $(this).jPlayer("pauseOthers");
    },
    pause: function(event){
        $(this).jPlayer("playHead", 0);
    },
    swfPath: "../../js",
    supplied: "mp3",
    wmode: "window",
    globalVolume: true,
    useStateClassSkin: true,
    autoBlur: false,
    smoothPlayBar: true,
    keyEnabled: true
});
```